# If my leave has expired while awaiting a decision, will I become an overstayer?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

My toursit visa will expire next month while I am waiting for an EEA family member residence card, does this make me an overstayer?

Comment: If you are a family member of an EEA citizen then you don't actually need the card and you can't really overstay. The problem arises of course if they decide you're not entitled to the card. The usual approach is that you're allowed to stay while the application is pending and they can't hold it against you if you do, but I don't remember the specific rules in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can prove you are waiting for a decision you will not be penalized as an overstayer.

I think you have to show your case number, but am only recalling from memory.

Whatever you do, don't leave the country you may not get back in.

If the decision comes back unfavourably, you will need to leave as soon as practical.